# How to customize Devise Invitable for different use cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to follow the documentation for Devise Invitable [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Customizing-for-different-Invite-use-cases-(emails-etc.)) to send different email for different user types, in my case **partners** and **clients**.

So it says to add in your Devise model, which in my case is `User.rb`, the following code.

```
....
  attr_accessor :invitation_instructions
....
    def self.invite_partner!(attributes={}, invited_by=nil)
      self.invite!(attributes, invited_by) do |invitable|
       invitable.invitation_instructions = :partner_invitation_instructions
      end
    end

    def self.invite_client!(attributes={}, invited_by=nil)
     self.invite!(attributes, invited_by) do |invitable|
       invitable.invitation_instructions = :client_invitation_instructions
     end
    end
```

Then from my controller, when a new user signs up I am calling

```
....
if current_user.is_client?
  user.invite_client!(user, current_user)
else
  user.invite_partner!(user, current_user)
end
```

When I do that the error I get back is

```
undefined method 'invite_client!' for #<User:0x007ffbcdfabd08>
```

Which is a little confusing because the method is defined in the user model, so I would think that, at least, it was defined.

Any help on fixing this and getting this setup to work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those are class methods and you should call it like `User.invite_client!` and also pass your arguments in method.

Same goes for `invite_partner!`